# Why do $\omega$, $k$, and electric susceptibility $\chi$ obey this relationship, assuming a dilute-gas?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, maxwell-equations, polarization, dielectric

In the course of writing an undergraduate-level term paper, I'm reading [this](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Esimonw/phys431/references/faraday/van_baak_Faraday_AmJPhysi1995.pdf) paper, which provides a simple derivation of the Becquerel relation ($\theta = \nu BL$, describing the Faraday effect) by modeling media as simple gas systems subject to uniform magnetic fields (leading to Zeeman splitting).

On the second page, the author provides [the electric susceptibility formula for linear dielectrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility#Definition_for_linear_dielectrics):

$$\vec{P} = \epsilon_0\chi \vec{E}$$

The author then notes that, for a dilute-gas sample, one does not need to distinguish between the incident and the "local" value of the electric field. The author goes on to say that, "under this assumption, Maxwell's equations give the relationship between wave number $k$ and frequency $\omega$ for any monochromatic plane wave propagating through the material":

$$\bigg(\frac{kc}{\omega}\bigg)^2 = 1+\chi$$

In the limit of low density, $|\chi|$ becomes sufficiently small that:

$$\frac{kc}{\omega} = 1 + \frac{\chi}{2}$$

The author goes on to state that "the usual decomposition of $\chi$ into real and imaginary parts ($\chi = \chi^{'} + i\chi^{''}$) gives the results":

$$n = 1+\frac{\chi^{'}}{2}\textrm{     and     }\beta = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\frac{\chi^{''}}{2}$$

It isn't clear to me, unfortunately, how Maxwell's equations yield the given relation between $k$, $\omega$, and $\chi$. Moreover, it isn't clear to me what is meant by the "usual decomposition" of $\chi$, nor (more importantly) how this leads to the given formula for $n$ and $\beta$.

**How were these two formulae obtained?**